# Why am I constantly logged out when using Stack Overflow on the iPad (not app)

Tags: support, bug, mobile-web

When using Stack Overflow on the iPad (safari) I constantly get logged out when viewing a question. I'm able to re login directly, but it (close to) always logs me out first. I know that I can use the app, but I'm still wondering why this happens.

Are there any explanations for why this happens?

Comment: Is that on http or on https links? Which openid provider are you using?

Comment: It's on http links, I use login with facebook only. @rene

Comment: Did this started recently or has it always been the case? No repro for me on Safari Windows (but that is an very old version)

Comment: It has been similar all the time, but I'd say its getting worse the last time

Comment: Hmmm, OK, we have to wait for dev to investigate....

Comment: I get this a lot as well. One moment I'm logged in then I go to another page and suddenly am logged out. There is a question about this on MSE http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243734/145673

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks. It seems that it's not my iPads problem... :-)

Comment: This happens to me on Android using the standard KitKat browser as well.  If I'm logged into SO main, it is infrequent (maybe 1/20 visits will suddenly log me ou), but as soon as I open a link to meta.SO, it logs me out.  Using Google as openid, I can _never_ successfully login to meta on mobile, so a click on any meta link guarantees I have to reenter credentials for the main site. I don't use Google/Android's stored-credentials-logged-into-browser-thing, whatever it's called.

Comment: Are you browsing in "private" mode?

Comment: For me - no to private mode. I thought at first it may be because I was whitelisting cookies (which might be a Cyanogenmod feature?), but after disabling that behavior and accepting all cookies, it persisted.

Comment: This happened to me over the summer, and it was a very annoying reoccurring issue. Since then, however, I have opted to use the app. 

My question from that time was closed+deleted as unreproducible (I can no longer find it). I was on an iPad running iOS 8 (beta at the time, and "unsupported").

 At the time it was thought to be a browser issue rather than anything to do with SO. Glad to see I wasn't going crazy.

Comment: For me no private mode, too. The iPad isn't jailbroken or whatever, just the standard version without any self made restrictions on anything.

Comment: Might be a reliance on 3rd party cookies which are off by default on iOS devices

Comment: I've been having the same problem with my iPhone on iOS 8 recently.

Comment: I have the same on vacation on my iPad3 iOS 8.x I have not considered using the app on iPad. Perhaps I should try.