# Weird view when 'partially' logged out

Tags: bug, logout, ipad

Since today, when I'm getting logged out while using the site on the iPad, I get a view like in the picture below

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "getting logged out"? Are you just using the site and end up logged out, or...?

Comment: @AnnaLear yes, like you said, please see this [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281713/why-am-i-constantly-logged-out-when-using-stack-overflow-on-the-ipad-not-app) from some time back, it appears after this logout

Comment: That's... weird. I'll take a look next week.

Comment: That's a cool feature

Comment: I agree @MCMastery :P :)

Comment: That's been happening to me too, for a few weeks now. I had assumed it was a memory issue (16gb fills up very quickly), but having cleared some apps and space the issue remains.

Comment: @michael What do you normally do? Just browse around the site? Post? Review? Only one site or do you go between several? Which browser are you using? The screenshot looks like Safari, but I wanna double check. Also, how often do the logouts happen?

Comment: @AnnaLear it's the iPad's build in safari browser on the latest OS, without any modifications made. It mostly happens when browsing through different questions, but like every 20th request ends in this kind of logout, no matter what I do. I didn't do any tests and take statistics about the behavior, so the number above is really vague. Is it reproducible for you?

Comment: @michael No, although I do appreciate the opportunity to just surf around for a while. :) I'll have to keep digging, hopefully something turns up.

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm using Facebook authentication for the site, if it helps you.  Enjoy surfing.

Comment: similar report [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302804/what-happend-to-the-main-page) with the difference that the user is logged in.