# What happened to the main page?

Tags: bug, design

Simply put, what is going on with Stack Overflow main page?

[image]

I'm not the only one experiencing [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300164/weird-view-when-partially-logged-out).

Comment: That's... wrong. What browser/platform are you on?

Comment: @AnnaLear I'm on chrome 44.0.2403.155 and Windows 10.

Comment: It's an screen echo caused by Microsoft's Windows 10 ripping your browser history.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I think [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300164/weird-view-when-partially-logged-out) is also a dupe that will qualify

Comment: @Persijn are you using facebook as your authentication provider, just as the user in the dupe I mentioned?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I'd be very surprised if that was related. That's just not how we render pages. Having said that... I have no idea why we're suddenly getting reports of these "nested" views (I haven't been able to reproduce any of them), so take my opinion with a grain of salt.

Comment: Looks like a dup of @rene question not the current one tagged, yet I'm not on a ipad or am i logging out. It was the first screen i watched when i went to the main page.

Comment: @Persijn Possible. I haven't been able to repro that one either. How did you get to this point? It looks like you're logged in... were you just browsing around?

Comment: @AnnaLear Okay, that's why I put the question mark at the end. I've retracted  my vote. This is a strange "bug" indeed. Should I remove the suggested dupe link?

Comment: @AnnaLear it was the very first page i viewed when i started my browser. (could it be a cache thing?) Its the first time it ever happened and refreshing fixed it.

Comment: Maybe let's not close this as a duplicate at all....

Comment: Not too worried about classifying it as a duplicate or not here, @Bjørn. I have no idea if it is. :)

Comment: I find the +1 rep the best part of the picture :D

Comment: @Persijn Interesting. Guess I'll keep an eye out for it. Thanks.

Comment: I've seen some of the reports and followed their trail, but I've been unable to reproduce this on my Firefox 40.0.2 on Vista Ultimate 64.

Comment: Inception! We must go deeper!

Comment: @Matt if (when) i find out how this happend i'll stackoverflow with a droste effect :D

Comment: they've got that [ten millionth question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299058/839601) at last?

Comment: I reproduced that a moment ago. I clicked a link to SO main page. It loaded with "need answer" questions visible. I clicked the button to show "new" questions and got inception-ed.

Comment: Also, why is the screenshot saying there are 96 questions on the site?

Comment: For someone that can reproduce this: it might be worthwhile to "inspect element" on the inner stackoverflow to figure out what element is doing the nesting (presumably an iframe?)

Comment: @gnat what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, when they reach that [meta-tag:10m-questions-milestone], strange things may happen at main page